# Annotation Transactional in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

Explain clearly what's @Transactional doing, but I still don't understand when should Spring Boot methods use this annotation:

For example:

I have this method:

```
void addPerson () {// code that calls the DAO layer}
```

My method will work well without the @Transactional annotation then why i should add this annotation.

More precisely (in spring boot) what's the difference between:

```
@Transactional void addPerson () {// code that calls the DAO layer}
```

and

```
void addPerson () {// code that calls the DAO layer}
```

Or does Spring boot add automatically this annotation so we don't need to add it to our services

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use @Transcational when concurrent calls on your API can affect each other.

Let's say you want to add a Person (you retreive data from somewhere, create a new Person from data and add it to a list of persons). Let's assume in order to create a Person you need a partner attribute which is another Person.

Before creating a Person you would search the partner by Id somehwere and add it to the new Person partner attribute. But what if during all this Queries the partneryou wanted to add is deleted somewhere (let's say in the database due to some other query). You'll end up not having the object you requested.

If you use @Transactional Spring makes sure all the required data is safe until the Transaction ends. Once it ends, the delete request from the partner would take place and then you'll have some logic to remove it from the new Person object. But that would take place afterwards.

You use @Transactional to ensure safety on your "Transactions".